# Div/Li with arrow format (breadcrumb)

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

How can I make a breadcrumb in pure HTML/CSS like this:

[image]

Comment: What have your tried? Can you post an example to work from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This css will help

```
/*custom font*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans);

* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html, body {min-height: 100%;}

body {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 100px;
    background: #689976;
    background: linear-gradient(#689976, #ACDACC);
    font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', arial, verdana;
}

.breadcrumb {
    /*centering*/
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*Lets add the numbers for each link using CSS counters. flag is the name of the counter. to be defined using counter-reset in the parent element of the links*/
    counter-reset: flag; 
}

.breadcrumb a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 36px;
    color: white;
    /*need more margin on the left of links to accomodate the numbers*/
    padding: 0 10px 0 60px;
    background: #666;
    background: linear-gradient(#666, #333);
    position: relative;
}
/*since the first link does not have a triangle before it we can reduce the left padding to make it look consistent with other links*/
.breadcrumb a:first-child {
    padding-left: 46px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; /*to match with the parent's radius*/
}
.breadcrumb a:first-child:before {
    left: 14px;
}
.breadcrumb a:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0; /*this was to prevent glitches on hover*/
    padding-right: 20px;
}

/*hover/active styles*/
.breadcrumb a.active, .breadcrumb a:hover{
    background: #333;
    background: linear-gradient(#333, #000);
}
.breadcrumb a.active:after, .breadcrumb a:hover:after {
    background: #333;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #333, #000);
}

/*adding the arrows for the breadcrumbs using rotated pseudo elements*/
.breadcrumb a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    right: -18px; /*half of square's length*/
    /*same dimension as the line-height of .breadcrumb a */
    width: 36px; 
    height: 36px;
    /*as you see the rotated square takes a larger height. which makes it tough to position it properly. So we are going to scale it down so that the diagonals become equal to the line-height of the link. We scale it to 70.7% because if square's: 
    length = 1; diagonal = (1^2 + 1^2)^0.5 = 1.414 (pythagoras theorem)
    if diagonal required = 1; length = 1/1.414 = 0.707*/
    transform: scale(0.707) rotate(45deg);
    /*we need to prevent the arrows from getting buried under the next link*/
    z-index: 1;
    /*background same as links but the gradient will be rotated to compensate with the transform applied*/
    background: #666;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #666, #333);
    /*stylish arrow design using box shadow*/
    box-shadow: 
        2px -2px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 
        3px -3px 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    /*
        5px - for rounded arrows and 
        50px - to prevent hover glitches on the border created using shadows*/
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 50px;
}
/*we dont need an arrow after the last link*/
.breadcrumb a:last-child:after {
    content: none;
}
/*we will use the :before element to show numbers*/
.breadcrumb a:before {
    content: counter(flag);
    counter-increment: flag;
    /*some styles now*/
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 30px;
    background: #444;
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #222);
    font-weight: bold;
}


.flat a, .flat a:after {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.flat a:before {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ccc;
}
.flat a:hover, .flat a.active, 
.flat a:hover:after, .flat a.active:after{
    background: #9EEB62;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- a simple div with some links -->
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <a href="#" class="active">Browse</a>
    <a href="#">Compare</a>
    <a href="#">Order Confirmation</a>
    <a href="#">Checkout</a>
</div>
<br /><br />
<!-- another version - flat style with animated hover effect -->
<div class="breadcrumb flat">
    <a href="#" class="active">Browse</a>
    <a href="#">Compare</a>
    <a href="#">Order Confirmation</a>
    <a href="#">Checkout</a>
</div>

<!-- Prefixfree -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/prefixfree-1.0.7.js" type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it, the solution:

CSS:

```
.pointer {
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    border-left-color: red;
}
.pointer:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid white;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
.pointer:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid;
    border-left-color: inherit;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
.pointer .text {
    padding-left: 22px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 100%">
    <div id="pointer" class="pointer">                    
          <span class="text">TEST</span>                    
    </div>
    <div id="pointer" class="pointer">                    
          <span class="text">TESTE 2</span>                    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll want to remove the `id="pointer"` or at least make them unique as it is invalid HTML.

Comment: Would make more sense semantically as `<ul class="breadcrumbs"> <li>TEST</li> <li>TEST 2 </li> </ul>` then styles could be based on `ul.breadcrumbs > li` ; a lot less markup too -- add the span within the li only if you can't do without it.